# Changing Jenkins build number

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to change the build number that is sent via email after a job completes?  The problem is that are product builds are NOT being done by Jenkins, so we want to be able to get the build number(ie. from a text file) and update the build number in Jenkins to match it.    I have tried to set the build number:

```
set BUILD_NUMBER=45
```

But the email is still showing the build number that Jenkins originally set.

Answer (score 375):

If you have access to the script console (Manage Jenkins -> Script Console), then you can do this following:

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("YourJobName").updateNextBuildNumber(45)
```

Comment: I can verify this works perfectly to solve the problem.  I manually copied build history between two jenkins servers, and on the new server nextBuildNumber was wrong.  Running this allowed me to set a correct new nextBuildNumber, no jenkins config reload required.

Comment: If you are using the GitHub plugin, `"YourJobName"` is `"organization/repository/branchname"`.

Comment: Works. The value can be verified without building using: `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("YourJobName").getNextBuildNumber()`

Comment: I can confirm this is also working for MultiBranch-Pipelines. The "JobName" is listed on the top of the branch page: Full project name: `PipelineName/BranchName` so it would be `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("YourPipelineName/YourBranchName").updateNextBuildNumber(45)`

Comment: @DanielAlder's comment has hidden characters in the statement and Jenkins cannot parse it correctly. Firefox only shows one of the characters that you can delete but there are more hidden ones that cause the statement not to work. Here is a copyable string: `Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("JobName").getNextBuildNumber()`

Comment: @Quantic I'm surprised, you are right. But your string contains the same characters. Output of hexdump: "B   u   i   � 200 214   � 200 213   l   d   N   u". I cannot explain it but the characters seem to be inserted by stackoverflow!

Comment: @Quantic https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356435/hidden-characters-in-comment

Comment: I tried this, I tried next build number plugin, I tried changing `nextBuildNumber` file content - nothing works. The latter just got overwritten by the next number, and others just have no effect. `getNnextBuildNumber()` returns not what I set, but the next incremental value. Not sure where it gets this from.

Comment: This is working. You have to enter the full name of the project

Comment: And if your branch name has a forward slash (e.g. feature/123), you will need to replace the Forward Slash with its Unicode character %2F (e.g. feature%2F123).

Comment: On a multibranch pipeline you must include the branch name at the end, so `pipeline/job/branch`.

Answer (score 40):

can be done with the plugin:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin

more info:
http://www.alexlea.me/2010/10/howto-set-hudson-next-build-number.html

if you don't like the plugin:

> If you want to change build number via nextBuildNumber file you should
>   "Reload Configuration from Disk" from "Manage Jenkins" page.

Comment: No need to use plugin.

Answer (score 33):

Under the job workspace folder, like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\job_name
```

there is a file named `nextBuildNumber`.

Setting the build number in the file and reloading the configuration from disk (Manage Jenkins menu) will force the next build you start to have the value from the file as BUILD_NUMBER.

Comment: Did you reload the configuration from disk (Manage Jenkins menu) after changing the nextBuildNumber file?

Comment: Nope! I thought it happened automatically.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. You have to reboot the server before it takes affect.

Comment: Having to reboot the server is a pain if you have many users running pipeline. Better avoid this kind of solution

Answer (score 10):

If you have branch name including **Forward Slash** (using **git flow** for example), you will need to replace the **Forward Slash** with its Unicode character **%2F** within the branch name.

Here is an example for the pipeline **My-Pipeline-Name** and the branch **release/my-release-branch-name**

```
Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("My-Pipeline-Name/release%2Fmy-release-branch-name").updateNextBuildNumber(BUILD_NUMBER)
```

I was able to find out about this by running the following command which will list the different jobs (branches) for your pipeline

```
Jenkins.instance.getItem("My-Pipeline-Name").getAllJobs()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a combination of these plugins may come in handy:

- [Parametrized build plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) - define some variable which holds your build number
- [Version number plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin) - use the variable to change the build number
- [Build name setter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) - use the variable to change the build number

Comment: Thanks a lot - I was able to use one of the plugins.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the build number by updating the file `${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/job_name/nextBuildNumber` on *Jenkins* server.

You can also install the plugin [Next Build Number plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/next-build-number/) to change build number using the *CLI* or a *UI*

Comment: Note that changing the build number in the nextBuildNumber file on its own is not enough, executing the "Reload Configuration from Disk" in "Manage Jenkins" menu is necessary as well.

Answer (score 4):

For multibranch pipeline projects, do this in the script console:

```
def project = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("YourMultibranchPipelineProjectName")    
project.getAllJobs().each{ item ->   
    
    if(item.name == 'jobName'){ // master, develop, feature/......
      
      item.updateNextBuildNumber(#Number);
      item.saveNextBuildNumber();
      
      println('new build: ' + item.getNextBuildNumber())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps: Jenkins Console > Manage Jenkins > Script Console, then write the script as:

Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("Your_job_name").updateNextBuildNumber(45)

Comment: Does this add any value to the top voted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901733/1796579 ?

Answer (score -6):

By using environmental variables:

```
$BUILD_NUMBER =4
```

Comment: Please, don't shout. Thank you.