# In Jenkins, how do I set the initial build number of a project created by a Multibranch project?

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I'm now using the Multibranch project type to build several branches in my Git repository without creating a project manually for each branch. This works well. However, when a new branch in Git causes a new project to be created, the first build number is always 1. I would like it to always be something else (thinking about 11000, but that's not important).

I haven't been able to find an approach to try. I've been reading a number of posts including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350667/how-to-set-next-build-number-in-multibranch-pipeline-for-a-particular-branch) but still don't have an answer.