# Is there a way to set next Build Number manually on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

After system restart where Jenkins is stored, one of the jobs is constantly failing it is trying to create bulid with number 1 but there is already 1400 past builds.  Is there a way to change it so the build will be created with correct increment so in this case 1401.

Full stactrace from jenkins:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [Directory]\builds\1 already existed; will 
not overwite with [Build.Name] #1
at hudson.model.RunMap.put(RunMap.java:189)
at jenkins.model.lazy.LazyBuildMixIn.newBuild(LazyBuildMixIn.java:178)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.newBuild(AbstractProject.java:1011)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:1210)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.createExecutable(AbstractProject.java:144)
at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:328)
at hudson.model.Executor$1.call(Executor.java:310)
at hudson.model.Queue._withLock(Queue.java:1251)
at hudson.model.Queue.withLock(Queue.java:1189)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:310)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a groovy script in `$JENKINS_URL/script` as follows:

```
item = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("jobName")
item.updateNextBuildNumber(1401)
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36901733/547270

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use the "Next Build Number" plugin to accomplish this: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin

Comment: Yes I saw that plugin, unfortunately I cannot use any new plugin's. This is a "frozen" environment for performance tests I i cannot install anything new there I was hoping that this number (or at least increment start) is sitting somewhere in configuration file smiling at me

Answer (score 0):

There is a file you can edit: `$JENKINS_HOME/jobs/../nextBuildNumber`

```
$ cat /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/my-project/branches/develop/nextBuildNumber
42
```

You will need to reload configuration after changing it.