# How to use jenkins version number plugin to reset the build number everyday 1 to use in the version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, version

How can i update the version build number everyday. I have a version format "${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}.${BUILDS_ALL_TIME}", my build version are based on the date and the build number.

```
 So i want to reset (or make it start from 1) the Build number everyday as the date changes.
```

Ex: 
   If today i have five builds then the version will "2019-09-10.5" and for tomorrow the if its the first build then i want the value to be "2019-09-11.1" but using the above values i'm getting the next build number in the next day build. i.e version="2019-09-11.6"

So How can i reset or make it to 1 every next day for the first Build.

Have tried using different options of the version build number but nothing worked as per my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another pipeline job with below mentioned content:

`node() {` 
 `stage('Cleaning the Jenkins project history'){`
`def myJob = Jenkins.instance.getItem('job_name_to_reset')`
`myJob.getBuilds().each { it.delete() }`
`myJob.nextBuildNumber = 1`
`myJob.save()`
}
}

Schedule this job to run everyday at midnight and it will delete the build history and reset the count to 0. 
Note: You need to deselect **Use Groovy Sandbox** option otherwise it will ask for script approval each time.

OR

If you don't want to delete the build history, then you can go with this approach: [Changing Jenkins build number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645430/changing-jenkins-build-number)

Comment: But this will delete my build history as well,  as i only need to reset every next the value of the "$BUILDS_ALL_TIME" or any other option/script kind that can be used to reset the minor version value.

Comment: I don't believe there's a need to delete the existing builds. Just reset the nextBuildNumber; see [Changing Jenkins build number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19645430/598141)

Comment: Agreed with @IanW

Comment: @RajnikantJaybhaye, then perhaps edit your answer, so he can mark as "answered"  :)