# Customise Jenkins results UI with custom logic t

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to add a button to the "Stage View" build results screen with some custom logic? When the build succeeds it pushes built packages out to a package manager and the "output" of the build is essentially a generated version string. I'd like users to be able to just click a button to copy that version string to clipboard.

Comment: What is your package manager? there are lots of plugins already out there. You might just be able to change your build number with something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645430/changing-jenkins-build-number

Comment: The version and package manager are irrelevant really. I have a string that's generated by the build and I want a button in the UI which copies the string to clipboard.